# Page Header in Report Viewer with dynamic text not rendering complete text when exporting to pdf

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a very simple report which has a Page header, body and footer. In the page header there is a text field which get text from the user input in a windows form. The text in the text box changes based on what user inputs. The issue I am having is, in the report viewer every thing is working i.e. when user inputs a large text, the text box is expanding as needed and every thing looks good. But when I export the same report to pdf it is not rendering the text box height right, in other words the page header is not changing accordingly so body is overlapping with text in the page header.

Since this is my first post I am not able to post any images to show the problem.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue.